# ClickHouse - How to remove node from cluster for reading?

Tags: database, clickhouse, yandex

#### Background

I'm beginning work to set up a ClickHouse cluster with 3 CH nodes. The first node (Node A) would be write-only, and the remaining 2 (Nodes B + C) would be read-only. By this I mean that writes for a given table to Node A would automatically replicate to Nodes B + C. When querying the cluster, reads would only be resolved against Nodes B + C.

The purpose for doing this is two-fold.

1. This datastore serves both real-time and background jobs. Both are high volume, only on the read side, so it makes sense to segment the traffic. Node A would be used for writing to the cluster and all background reads. Nodes B + C would be strictly used for the UX.
2. The volume of writes is very low, perhaps 1 write per 10,000 reads. Data is entirely refreshed once per week. Background jobs need to be certain that the most current data is being read before they can be kicked off. Reading off of replicas introduces eventual consistency as a concern, so reading from the node directly (rather than the cluster) from Node A guarantees the data to be strongly consistent.

#### Question

I'm not finding much specific information in the CH documentation, and am wondering whether this might be possible. If so, what would the cluster configuration look like?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do so. But wouldn't the best solution be to read and write to each server sequentially using the Distributed table?

Comment: I've modified the question to provide more context on the reasoning. Please let me know your thoughts!